# Pre-cache site as user visits

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I am making a static site which is 'forced' to be cached via `Cache-control`, etc.

When a user visits my site, I want the browser to crawl my site, caching pages, so when the user navigates to a page, the load is almost instant.

(I do not need a recursive crawl, as that will probably happen as the user navigates between pages.  I just need to crawl the links on the current page, and of course not re-caching a page which has already been cached.)

(Also, I am not changing pages using Ajax-like techniques.  These are essentially normal flat HTML files with normal links.)

How can I do this pre-caching using Javascript?  (I am using jQuery.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache : true, type : 'GET' });

$('a').each(
    function()
    {
        $.ajax({ url : $(this).attr('href') });
    }
);
```

But I am not sure your browser will cache the page for further use without using an XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: This was my approach. In my experience, the XmlHttpRequest object caches page requests unless told otherwise - and that cache is valid whether or not subsequent requests are "natural" browser requests or further AJAX calls. If you're forcing a cache header to the client, any AJAX calls to the link hrefs on the page should achieve the pre-cache behavior you are asking for. Of course, this is just behavior that I've experienced - I can't say if this is behavior that one should count on.

Comment: For some reason Firefox doesn't ALWAYS respect the caching I set up in Ajax requests.  It works for most requests, though, and it always keeps the caches so page navigations are speedy.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not only caching of the static content, lots of things need to be done for improving website performance look at [Enhancing user browser experience](http://amareswar.blogspot.com/2009/10/enhancing-user-experience-by-improving.html)

Comment: I understand that.  I want to *pre*cache the pages, so it's already cached before the user visits.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the new HTML5 feature that is the [Cache Manifest](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html#manifest).

Comment: I should have mentioned this needs to work reasonably with IE7/8, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: Well this is one of the things that won't be even noticed on browsers that don't support it, so I'd recommend doing it anyway.

Comment: Otherwise you might be interested in this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Link_prefetching_FAQ